# What is the shorthand for setting up dependencies in jQuery deferred objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, dom-events, jquery-deferred

Do jQuery deferred objects have any shorthand to set up dependencies, i.e. "when I'm done, that thing is done as well?"  The below feels cumbersome:

```
a = new jQuery.Deferred();
b = new jQuery.Deferred();

a.done(function(result){alert(result);});
b.done(function(result){a.resolve(result);}); // this line doesn't feel right

b.resolve("Hey there!")
```

I'd love something like `b.alsoResolves(a)`.  I've looked at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), but can't seem to find anything appropriate. Is there any better way to created dependencies between deferred objects than the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are able to [register multiple callbacks sequentially now](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/), I personally find it cleaner to set dependencies this way:

```
a = $.Deferred();
b = $.Deferred();

a.done(fncDoStuffForA);

b.done(fncDoStuffForB);
b.done(a.resolve)

b.resolve("Hey there!")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/cdkG3/